Maybe others want to split the cost to improve FormBuilder's "Existing Contact" functionality?
I have just submitted an issue for the core team to develop the "Existing Contact" functionality to behave more like it does in Webform where, if a contact is not found, an "Add New" option is selectable. My org will pay for this development but we are wondering if other's might want to chip in also.

It does provide an option to include a profile for creating on a contact reference field.


Thanks... Yes, after looking at this more I think I will try to use it as it already is.
